# How to randomize seed in C#

Tags: c#, random

I need to generate random int in C#. I am using clock time to set the seend. However, as the rnd.Next() function may take less than a millisecond, this does not work if one has to generate a list of ints.

```
        for( int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            int max_val = 10; // max value
            var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            int randind = rnd.Next(0, max_val);
            Console.WriteLine(randind);
        }
```

Output:
    1
    5
    5
    5
    5

How can one randomise the seed in a clean way without adding an ugly sleep?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your `Random`object outside the loop and don't provide the seed parameter -- one will be picked for you. By taking it out of the loop, rnd.Next() will give you a random sequence anyway.

```
   var rnd = new Random();     
   for( int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        int max_val = 10; // max value
        int randind = rnd.Next(0, max_val);
        Console.WriteLine(randind);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Guid` object guaranties a different result each time. You could do this:

```
... new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())
```

Comment: The guid's expensive, and the hashcode's not guaranteed to be unique, so you're better off ignoring the seed constructor and just not constructing the Random instances over and over.